# AttributeError in Python sub-class when accessing a parent's attribute

Tags: python

I'd like to add some functionalities to the class [PlyElement](https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile/blob/master/plyfile.py) by creating the subclass PlyElementPlus.
I prefer to give you the real code snippet because it may be more useful to understand what's going on. Anyway the problem is related to classes and protected variables.

```
class PlyElementPlus(PlyElement):
    def __init__(self, element):
        super().__init__(element.name, element.properties, element.count)
        self.names = list(element.data.dtype.names)
        self.types = [str(element.data[n].dtype) for n in self.names]

mesh = PlyData.read(fname)         # This is a PlyData
vertex = mesh['vertex']            # This is a PlyElement
print(vertex.data[0]['x'])         # works 
>>> -1.60847
print(vertex[0]['x'])              # direct indexing works 
>>> -1.60847

vertex = PlyElementPlus(vertex)     # This is a PlyElementPlus
print(vertex.data[0]['x'])          # doesn't work
>>> AttributeError: 'PlyElementPlus' object has no attribute '_data'
```

Here there is part of PlyElement which may be helpful to understand the error:

```
class PlyElement(object):
    def __init__(self, name, properties, count, comments=[]):
    ...
    
    def _get_data(self):
        return self._data

    def _set_data(self, data):
        self._data = data

    data = property(_get_data, _set_data)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
```

Other methods or attributes which are not 'protected' are callable from my subclass, while 'data' is not. Moreover, data is accessible by direct indexing and I'd like my subclass to reproduce the same behaviour.
Can you help me?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with stuff being "protected" or not. Your object just doesn't have a `data` attribute. No value of `data` was ever set.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, as by default a `PlyElement` has no attribute `_data`, which is required, when you access `.data`:

```py
    def _get_data(self):
        return self._data

    data = property(_get_data, _set_data)]
```

The `_data` attribute is available after `PlyElements._read()` is called, which is done by the `PlyData` when calling its `.read()` method; Line 397 in this [file](https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile/blob/4df88d856bb9889cddc85cbb0ecf3b007e97fa0c/plyfile.py#L635).

So, as it says in the documentation,

```
    A client of this library doesn't normally need to instantiate this
    directly, so the following is only for the sake of documenting the
    internals.
```

it's usually not a good idea to instantiate this yourself, however, not having looked into all the details, you could get away with adding

```
self._data = element._data
```

to your `__init__()`.